# Parallel threads doing the same until a barrier, after barrier the result is not always the same

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, barrier

Several threads increment a value in an array in parallel. Every thread increments its own value, not changing the one of the others. After each incrementation we have a barrier so that threads wait for each other and continue to the next loop iteration only when all are done. This way, I suppose, every time all the threads reach the barrier, the values in every array element are equal. However, it is not always the case. Why is this not always the case?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    const int num_threads = 4;
    const auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> arr(num_threads, 0);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads)
    {
        int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
        while (true) {
            // Check elapsed time
            auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - start_time).count();
            if (elapsed >= 10) break;

            
            arr[thread_num]++;
            std::cout << "Thread " << thread_num << " done grinding.\n";
            
            #pragma omp barrier // Wait for other threads

            // Read other threads' values
            for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
                if (i != thread_num && arr[i] != arr[thread_num]) {
                    std::cout << "Thread " << thread_num << ": My value is " << arr[thread_num] 
                              << ", but thread " << i << "'s value is " << arr[i] << ".\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Final array values:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Index " << i << ": " << arr[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output (the end of it):

```
Thread 3 done grinding.
Thread 2 done grinding.
Thread 1: My value is 271402, but thread 2's value is 271403.
Thread 1 done grinding.
Thread 3: My value is 271402, but thread 1's value is 271403.
Thread 3: My value is 271402, but thread 2's value is 271403.
Thread 0: My value is 271402, but thread 2's value is 271403.
Thread 1: My value is 271403, but thread 0's value is 271402.
Thread 1: My value is 271403, but thread 3's value is 271402.
Thread 2: My value is 271403, but thread 0's value is 271402.
Thread 2: My value is 271403, but thread 3's value is 271402.
Final array values:
Index 0: 271402
Index 1: 271403
Index 2: 271403
Index 3: 271402
```

Comment: I'm surprised the numbers are that close together.  Based on "you have 10 seconds of time to increment as much as you can", each accumulation for each thread can vary greatly, because they're highly sensitive to the scheduler and the number of physical or logical cores on the machine.

Comment: You're doing standard output inside a parallel region. Don't. You have no idea how the operating system interferes with the openmp parallelism.

Comment: @Eljay I wonder if Roman is only humble bragging about how great his cpu is, because mine only does about 100k in 10 seconds and it has many 'out of sync' reports amidst the run as well from uneven scheduling.

Comment: Actually, I have something to do with OpenMP in a very short time and I have not much experience with C++ and none with OpenMP. The code is mostly produced by ChatGPT and is a proof of concept for me. My processor is Apple M2 and I've had no idea if this is fast or not, and neither I've had interest in this matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as written hangs nearly every time I run it, never finishing, because one of the threads gets stuck at the barrier waiting for the others that already terminated. This happens because some thread checks `elapsed` at 9.99999 seconds and proceeds but another thread checks at 10 and exits. This is also why the finish count can be higher on some threads than on others because they go an extra round, also amid the run the increment values are sometimes not equal because some threads spend longer in the for loop printing out their current value than others who have already proceeded to wrap around to the next barrier to wait.

In order to terminate the threads appropriately and to synchronize them perfectly a flag is needed which will be `#pragma omp flush`ed in order to break the threads at the same time, also another barrier after the increment comparison and print for loop is needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{

    const auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const int num_threads = 4;
    std::vector<int> arr(num_threads, 0);
    bool breakFlag = false;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_threads) default(none) shared(start_time,arr,std::cout, breakFlag)
    {

        int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
        while (true) {
            // Check elapsed time
            auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - start_time).count();
            if (elapsed >= 10) breakFlag = true;


            arr[thread_num]++;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Thread " << thread_num << " done grinding.\n";
            std::cout << ss.str();

#pragma omp barrier // Wait for other threads
#pragma omp flush(breakFlag)
            if(breakFlag) break;

            // Read other threads' values
            for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
                if (i != thread_num && arr[i] != arr[thread_num]) {
                    std::stringstream _ss;
                    _ss << "Thread " << thread_num << ": My value is " << arr[thread_num]
                              << ", but thread " << i << "'s value is " << arr[i] << ".\n";
                    std::cout << _ss.str();
                }
            }
#pragma omp barrier // Wait for other threads

        }
    }

    std::cout << "Final array values:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Index " << i << ": " << arr[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `barrier` construct contains an implicit `flush`, so I think the [flush construct](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu96.html) is not needed in this case.